# Indexing a data.table with a data.table of indices

Tags: r, indexing, data.table

Suppose I have two data.tables:

```
indexDT <- data.table(id = rep(c(1,2,3),c(3,2,1)), V1 = c(1,3,5,2,4,4) , V3= c(3,4,5, 4, 5,5))
DT <- data.table(id = rep(1:3,(rep(5,3))), data.table(sapply(1:3, function(i){rnorm(5*3)})))

setkey(indexDT,"id")
setkey(DT,"id")
```

ie,

```
#> indexDT
#   id V1 V3
#1:  1  1  3
#2:  1  3  4
#3:  1  5  5
#4:  2  2  4
#5:  2  4  5
#6:  3  4  5

#> DT
#     id          V1         V2         V3
#1:  1  0.30093680  2.0481465  0.7207622
#2:  1 -0.79176664 -1.0024393 -1.5915616
#3:  1  0.57746018 -1.1214380 -0.6158101
#4:  1 -1.61781064  0.3569482 -1.2155334
#5:  1 -0.14585645 -2.0758002 -0.6914313
#6:  2  1.16340667  0.7991301  0.1155552
#7:  2  0.08072223 -1.2330383  1.3123562
#8:  2 -1.07706321  0.1705363 -0.6569734
#9:  2 -0.98598985 -0.5853677 -1.2507563
#10:  2 -0.16048051 -1.9341206  0.1300098
#11:  3 -0.39287015  0.2486458 -0.2215037
#12:  3  0.84511312  0.2084681  1.3388653
#13:  3 -0.09892791 -2.3361669  1.6006061
#14:  3 -0.01676263 -1.7047148 -0.2918755
#15:  3 -0.43500633 -0.8481987  0.3053506
```

The values in indexDT serve as row indices for each id for each of the columns names. Now I would like to do the following: For each column in indexDT (here: V1 and V3) and each id (here 1,2, and 3) select the values in DT according to the same column and id.
One solution is the following but this one is not very elegant, hard to read, and I was hoping that there is a faster solution. Both the indexDT and DT are very large (DT is nrow = 500k*26 and nrow = +/- 10k)

```
Ind_p <- grep("V",names(indexDT),value=T)
selectionDT <- DT[, lapply(Ind_p,function(p,k){.SD[indexDT[id == k, ][[p]], ][[p]]},id), by = id, .SDcol = Ind_p]
```

this gives

```
#> selectionDT 
#   id          V1         V2
#1:  1  0.30093680 -0.6158101
#2:  1  0.57746018 -1.2155334
#3:  1 -0.14585645 -0.6914313
#4:  2  0.08072223 -1.2507563
#5:  2 -0.98598985  0.1300098
#6:  3 -0.01676263  0.3053506
```

Any better solution to this would be greatly appreciated!!!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use substitution of matrices by a matrix of indices to do this:

```
DT[, names(indexDT), with = F][indexDT[, .(M = list(as.matrix(.SD))), keyby = id],
     as.data.table(matrix(as.matrix(.SD)[cbind(c(t(M[[1]])), 1:ncol(M[[1]]))],
                          ncol = ncol(M[[1]]), byrow = T)), by = .EACHI]
#   id          V1         V2
#1:  1 -0.08786187 -1.1277373
#2:  1 -0.62336535  0.5501641
#3:  1  1.09400253 -0.8152316
#4:  2 -1.01158421  2.0713417
#5:  2 -0.08669810 -0.3845776
#6:  3 -0.10041684 -0.2430609
```

The `cbind` inside constructs the matrix of indices, and the rest is just converting data to correct types.